# creating custom UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Can we create UITableView with UITableView cell in horizontal as well as vertically aligned

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: This UI you are showing is not a table view.

Comment: I know but I want to create it as a tableview . So that I pass a array to it and it will show a nice UI as shown in image. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to create it as a tableview?

Comment: So that, after providing array UI is populated automatically. As I need to to display this kind of UI dynamically.

Comment: Did you find any method to do this..?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its possible to modify the `UITableView` and add cell rows that contain multiple views set to be in horizontal order, but that would require a lot of custom work, too much in my opinion, you will lose the benefit of using a UITableView,

What i suggest here is to create your custom view, that has it custom DataSource and Delegate, and create your own view drawing logic, since this is a fairly complex view, it will require more work to customize your table view, than creating a ne `UIView` subclass